# matching pattern difference between `([, ]+)` and `([, ])+`

Tags: python, regex

```
IDLE 1.1.4      
>>> import re
>>> some_text = 'alpha, beta,,,,gamma   delta'
>>> re.split('[, ]+', some_text)
['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta']
# when the pattern doesn't contain parentheses, the returned values 
# only include matched substrings but separators.

>>> re.split('([, ]+)', some_text)
['alpha', ', ', 'beta', ',,,,', 'gamma', '   ', 'delta']
# returned values include separators and I can guess how it works.

>>> re.split('([, ])+', some_text)
['alpha', ' ', 'beta', ',', 'gamma', ' ', 'delta']
# Now I cannot even guess what is going on here.
```

**Question**> What is the difference between `'([, ]+)'` and `'([, ])+'`?
How it affects the returned values?

Comment: You might want to try just matching with `re.search()`, and see what the matches are; `split`'s behavior with groups introduces additional complexity here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`([, ]+)` says "match one or more commas and/or spaces and capture them as a group", thus in your second example your see the whole string of separator characaters returned in one group.

`([, ])+` says "match one comma or space, and capture one or more groups of these".  So in your third example, each separator character is captured in it's own group, and you're only getting the last of these each time.

Answer (score 4):

The former places all instances of " " and "," in a run into a group, whereas the latter returns a group only containing the last.

Answer (score 2):

if there is `,,,,` in your string, when your pattern is `([, ]+)` this group will return `,,,,` and if your pattern is `([, ])+` it will return `,`

Answer (score 1):

Watch your matching groups.

- `([, ]+)` this matches 1 or more occurrences of `,` or a space and returns them all, which catches long chains of those characters.
- `([, ])+` this matches either a space or a `,` and returns it as a group.

Comment: When the pattern is '([, ])+', how to explain the second returned item ' '? The substring between alpha and beta contains ', ' why it only returns ' '?

Comment: If it found `,` first, why returns `' '` first?

Comment: Because it splits the string at that point. Use `re.search()` instead of `re.sub()` to see better.

Answer (score 1):

Change your commas to ABCD as below to see it visually:

some_text2 = 'alphaA betaABCDgamma   delta'

re.split('([ABCD ])+', some_text2)

['alpha', ' ', 'beta', 'D', 'gamma', ' ', 'delta']

Its actually matching each comma, but as 1 character group. The + is turns it into a greedy match until it no longer matches the letters in the character class.

Try without the +

re.split('([ABCD ])', some_text2)

['alpha',
 'A',
 '',
 ' ',
 'beta',
 'A',
 '',
 'B',
 '',
 'C',
 '',
 'D',
 'gamma',
 ' ',
 '',
 ' ',
 '',
 ' ',
 'delta']